# How to split read-only and read-write transactions with JPA and Hibernate

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, jpa, replication

I have a quite heavy java webapp that serves thousands of requests/sec and it uses a master Postgresql db which replicates itself to one secondary (read-only) database using streaming (asynchronous) replication.

So, I separate the request from primary to secondary(read-only) using URLs to avoid read-only calls to bug primary database considering replication time is minimal.

**NOTE**: *I use one sessionFactory with a RoutingDataSource provided by spring that looks up db to use based on a key. I am interested in multitenancy as I am using hibernate 4.3.4 that supports it.*

I have two questions:

1. I dont think splitting on the basis of URLs is efficient as I can
   only move 10% of traffic around means there are not many read-only 
   URLs. What approach should I consider?
2. May be,somehow, on the basis of URLs I achieve some level of
   distribution among both nodes but what would I do with my quartz
       jobs(that even have separate JVM)? What pragmatic approach should I 
       take?

I know I might not get a perfect answer here as this really is broad but I just want your opinion for the context.

Dudes I have in my team:

- Spring4
- Hibernate4
- Quartz2.2
- Java7 / Tomcat7

Please take interest. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'd have two persistence units - one for read-only, and one for read-write, work. The read-only one might point to a PgBouncer that backs on to multiple PostgreSQL replicas. Then I'd pick which to use based on the particular method invoked on my data access abstraction objects and other relevant context. You have to think very carefully about logical consistency if you do this though, and avoid read/modify/write cycles.

Comment: **User tracking** is an area that can be optimized, if not already done: separation into R/O + R+W tables, session held cache, written out. **Archiving tables** that only receive new records, but the records being immutable, can be split too in R/O and R+W, possibly with DB triggers.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

### Spring transaction routing

First, we will create a `DataSourceType` Java Enum that defines our transaction routing options:

```
public enum  DataSourceType {
    READ_WRITE,
    READ_ONLY
}
```

To route the read-write transactions to the Primary node and read-only transactions to the Replica node, we can define a `ReadWriteDataSource` that connects to the Primary node and a `ReadOnlyDataSource` that connect to the Replica node.

The read-write and read-only transaction routing is done by the Spring [`AbstractRoutingDataSource`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/datasource/lookup/AbstractRoutingDataSource.html) abstraction, which is implemented by the `TransactionRoutingDatasource`, as illustrated by the following diagram:

[image: Read-write and read-only transaction routing with Spring]

The `TransactionRoutingDataSource` is very easy to implement and looks as follows:

```
public class TransactionRoutingDataSource 
        extends AbstractRoutingDataSource {

    @Nullable
    @Override
    protected Object determineCurrentLookupKey() {
        return TransactionSynchronizationManager
            .isCurrentTransactionReadOnly() ?
            DataSourceType.READ_ONLY :
            DataSourceType.READ_WRITE;
    }
}
```

Basically, we inspect the Spring `TransactionSynchronizationManager` class that stores the current transactional context to check whether the currently running Spring transaction is read-only or not.

The `determineCurrentLookupKey` method returns the discriminator value that will be used to choose either the read-write or the read-only JDBC `DataSource`.

### Spring read-write and read-only JDBC DataSource configuration

The `DataSource` configuration looks as follows:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(
    basePackages = "com.vladmihalcea.book.hpjp.util.spring.routing"
)
@PropertySource(
    "/META-INF/jdbc-postgresql-replication.properties"
)
public class TransactionRoutingConfiguration 
        extends AbstractJPAConfiguration {

    @Value("${jdbc.url.primary}")
    private String primaryUrl;

    @Value("${jdbc.url.replica}")
    private String replicaUrl;

    @Value("${jdbc.username}")
    private String username;

    @Value("${jdbc.password}")
    private String password;

    @Bean
    public DataSource readWriteDataSource() {
        PGSimpleDataSource dataSource = new PGSimpleDataSource();
        dataSource.setURL(primaryUrl);
        dataSource.setUser(username);
        dataSource.setPassword(password);
        return connectionPoolDataSource(dataSource);
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource readOnlyDataSource() {
        PGSimpleDataSource dataSource = new PGSimpleDataSource();
        dataSource.setURL(replicaUrl);
        dataSource.setUser(username);
        dataSource.setPassword(password);
        return connectionPoolDataSource(dataSource);
    }

    @Bean
    public TransactionRoutingDataSource actualDataSource() {
        TransactionRoutingDataSource routingDataSource = 
            new TransactionRoutingDataSource();

        Map<Object, Object> dataSourceMap = new HashMap<>();
        dataSourceMap.put(
            DataSourceType.READ_WRITE, 
            readWriteDataSource()
        );
        dataSourceMap.put(
            DataSourceType.READ_ONLY, 
            readOnlyDataSource()
        );

        routingDataSource.setTargetDataSources(dataSourceMap);
        return routingDataSource;
    }

    @Override
    protected Properties additionalProperties() {
        Properties properties = super.additionalProperties();
        properties.setProperty(
            "hibernate.connection.provider_disables_autocommit",
            Boolean.TRUE.toString()
        );
        return properties;
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] packagesToScan() {
        return new String[]{
            "com.vladmihalcea.book.hpjp.hibernate.transaction.forum"
        };
    }

    @Override
    protected String databaseType() {
        return Database.POSTGRESQL.name().toLowerCase();
    }

    protected HikariConfig hikariConfig(
            DataSource dataSource) {
        HikariConfig hikariConfig = new HikariConfig();
        int cpuCores = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();
        hikariConfig.setMaximumPoolSize(cpuCores * 4);
        hikariConfig.setDataSource(dataSource);

        hikariConfig.setAutoCommit(false);
        return hikariConfig;
    }

    protected HikariDataSource connectionPoolDataSource(
            DataSource dataSource) {
        return new HikariDataSource(hikariConfig(dataSource));
    }
}
```

The `/META-INF/jdbc-postgresql-replication.properties` resource file provides the configuration for the read-write and read-only JDBC `DataSource` components:

```
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL10Dialect

jdbc.url.primary=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/high_performance_java_persistence
jdbc.url.replica=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/high_performance_java_persistence_replica

jdbc.username=postgres
jdbc.password=admin
```

The `jdbc.url.primary` property defines the URL of the Primary node while the `jdbc.url.replica` defines the URL of the Replica node.

The `readWriteDataSource` Spring component defines the read-write JDBC `DataSource` while the `readOnlyDataSource` component define the read-only JDBC `DataSource`.

> Note that both the read-write and read-only data sources use HikariCP for connection pooling.

The `actualDataSource` acts as a facade for the read-write and read-only data sources and is implemented using the `TransactionRoutingDataSource` utility.

The `readWriteDataSource` is registered using the `DataSourceType.READ_WRITE` key and the `readOnlyDataSource` using the `DataSourceType.READ_ONLY` key.

So, when executing a read-write `@Transactional` method, the `readWriteDataSource` will be used while when executing a `@Transactional(readOnly = true)` method, the `readOnlyDataSource` will be used instead.

> Note that the `additionalProperties` method defines the `hibernate.connection.provider_disables_autocommit` Hibernate property, which I added to Hibernate to postpone the database acquisition for RESOURCE_LOCAL JPA transactions.
>
> Not only that the [`hibernate.connection.provider_disables_autocommit`](https://vladmihalcea.com/why-you-should-always-use-hibernate-connection-provider_disables_autocommit-for-resource-local-jpa-transactions/) allows you to make better use of database connections, but it's the only way we can make this example work since, without this configuration, the connection is acquired prior to calling the `determineCurrentLookupKey` method `TransactionRoutingDataSource`.

The remaining Spring components needed for building the JPA `EntityManagerFactory` are defined by the [`AbstractJPAConfiguration`](https://github.com/vladmihalcea/high-performance-java-persistence/blob/master/core/src/test/java/com/vladmihalcea/book/hpjp/util/spring/config/jpa/AbstractJPAConfiguration.java) base class.

Basically, the `actualDataSource` is further wrapped by DataSource-Proxy and provided to the JPA `EntityManagerFactory`. You can check the [source code on GitHub](https://github.com/vladmihalcea/high-performance-java-persistence) for more details.

### Testing time

To check if the transaction routing works, we are going to enable the PostgreSQL query log by setting the following properties in the `postgresql.conf` configuration file:

```
log_min_duration_statement = 0
log_line_prefix = '[%d] '
```

The `log_min_duration_statement` property setting is for logging all PostgreSQL statements while the second one adds the database name to the SQL log.

So, when calling the `newPost` and `findAllPostsByTitle` methods, like this:

```
Post post = forumService.newPost(
    "High-Performance Java Persistence",
    "JDBC", "JPA", "Hibernate"
);

List<Post> posts = forumService.findAllPostsByTitle(
    "High-Performance Java Persistence"
);
```

We can see that PostgreSQL logs the following messages:

```
[high_performance_java_persistence] LOG:  execute <unnamed>: 
    BEGIN

[high_performance_java_persistence] DETAIL:  
    parameters: $1 = 'JDBC', $2 = 'JPA', $3 = 'Hibernate'
[high_performance_java_persistence] LOG:  execute <unnamed>: 
    select tag0_.id as id1_4_, tag0_.name as name2_4_ 
    from tag tag0_ where tag0_.name in ($1 , $2 , $3)

[high_performance_java_persistence] LOG:  execute <unnamed>: 
    select nextval ('hibernate_sequence')

[high_performance_java_persistence] DETAIL:  
    parameters: $1 = 'High-Performance Java Persistence', $2 = '4'
[high_performance_java_persistence] LOG:  execute <unnamed>: 
    insert into post (title, id) values ($1, $2)

[high_performance_java_persistence] DETAIL:  
    parameters: $1 = '4', $2 = '1'
[high_performance_java_persistence] LOG:  execute <unnamed>: 
    insert into post_tag (post_id, tag_id) values ($1, $2)

[high_performance_java_persistence] DETAIL:  
    parameters: $1 = '4', $2 = '2'
[high_performance_java_persistence] LOG:  execute <unnamed>: 
    insert into post_tag (post_id, tag_id) values ($1, $2)

[high_performance_java_persistence] DETAIL:  
    parameters: $1 = '4', $2 = '3'
[high_performance_java_persistence] LOG:  execute <unnamed>: 
    insert into post_tag (post_id, tag_id) values ($1, $2)

[high_performance_java_persistence] LOG:  execute S_3: 
    COMMIT
    
[high_performance_java_persistence_replica] LOG:  execute <unnamed>: 
    BEGIN
    
[high_performance_java_persistence_replica] DETAIL:  
    parameters: $1 = 'High-Performance Java Persistence'
[high_performance_java_persistence_replica] LOG:  execute <unnamed>: 
    select post0_.id as id1_0_, post0_.title as title2_0_ 
    from post post0_ where post0_.title=$1

[high_performance_java_persistence_replica] LOG:  execute S_1: 
    COMMIT
```

The log statements using the `high_performance_java_persistence` prefix were executed on the Primary node while the ones using the `high_performance_java_persistence_replica` on the Replica node.

### GitHub Repository

This is not just theory. It's all on GitHub and works like a charm. Use [this test case](https://github.com/vladmihalcea/high-performance-java-persistence/blob/master/core/src/test/java/com/vladmihalcea/book/hpjp/spring/transaction/routing/TransactionRoutingDataSourceTest.java) as a reference.

So you can you use it a starting point for your transaction routing solution, as you have a fully-functional example.

### Second-level caching

Once you are using replication, you are operating in a distributed environment, so you need to use a distributed caching solution, like [Infinispan](https://infinispan.org/).

Since we are using replication to distribute traffic to more database nodes, it's obvious that we also have multiple application nodes which have to connect to those database nodes.

Therefore, using the `READ_WRITE` `CacheConcurrencyStrategy` in such an environment is a terrible anti-pattern as each distributed node will keep its own copy of the cached entries, leading you to consistency issues even if you didn't use transaction routing.

Not to mention the cold cache issue you'd face if you employed auto-scaling for your application nodes, as they would amplify the database traffic because new nodes would start with a cold cache.

> So, if you plan to use transaction routing with the second-level cache mechanism, then you can do better than this.
>
> Use the `NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE` cache concurrency strategy with a second-level caching provider that can store the cached data in a distributed system of nodes that are readily available even when you create new application nodes.

### Conclusion

You need to make sure you set the right size for your connection pools because that can make a huge difference. For this, I recommend using [Flexy Pool](https://github.com/vladmihalcea/flexy-pool).

You need to be very diligent and make sure you mark all read-only transactions accordingly. It's unusual that only 10% of your transactions are read-only. Could it be that you have such a write-most application or you are using write transactions where you only issue query statements?

For batch processing, you definitely need read-write transactions, so make sure you enable JDBC batching, like this:

```
<property name="hibernate.order_updates" value="true"/>
<property name="hibernate.order_inserts" value="true"/>
<property name="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size" value="25"/>
```

For batching you can also use a separate `DataSource` that uses a different connection pool that connects to the Primary node.

Just make sure your total connection size of all connection pools is less than the number of connections PostgreSQL has been configured with.

Each batch job must use a dedicated transaction, so make sure you use a reasonable batch size.

More, you want to hold locks and to finish transactions as fast as possible. If the batch processor is using concurrent processing workers, make sure the associated connection pool size is equal to the number of workers, so they don't wait for others to release connections.

Comment: Now that vlad-mihalcea removed its comments, the conversation makes no sense. The full transcript including vlad-mihalcea comments can be found at https://github.com/reda-alaoui/ro-rw-routing/blob/master/so-transcript.md .

Comment: My automated test exhibits the 2nd level cache issue with READ_WRITE *and* NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE CacheConcurrencyStrategy. See https://github.com/reda-alaoui/ro-rw-routing/blob/non-strict-read-write-cache/src/test/java/me/redaalaoui/ro_rw_routing/RoRwRoutingApplicationTests.java for NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE test.

Answer (score 5):

You are saying that your application URL's are only 10% read only so the other 90% have at least some form of database writing.

**10% READ**

You can think about using a [CQRS design](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/CQRS.html) that may improve your database read performance. It can certainly read from the secondary database, and possibly be made more efficient by designing the queries and domain models specifically for the read/view layer.

You haven't said whether the 10% requests are expensive or not (e.g. running reports)

I would prefer to use a separate sessionFactory if you were to follow the CQRS design as the objects being loaded/cached will most likely be different to those being written.

**90% WRITE**

As far as the other 90% go, you wouldn't want to read from the secondary database (while writing to the primary) during some write logic as you will not want potentially stale data involved.

Some of these reads are likely to be looking up "static" data. If Hibernate's caching is not reducing database hits for reads, I would consider an in memory cache like [Memcached](https://code.google.com/p/hibernate-memcached/) or Redis for this type of data. This same cache could be used by both 10%-Read and 90%-write processes.

For reads that are not static (i.e. reading data you have recently written) Hibernate should hold data in its object cache if its' sized appropriately. Can you determine your cache hit/miss performance?

**QUARTZ**

If you know for sure that a scheduled job won't impact the same set of data as another job, you could run them against different databases, however if in doubt always perform batch updates to one (primary) server and replicate changes out. It is better to be logically correct, than to introduce replication issues.

**DB PARTITIONING**

If your 1,000 requests per second are writing a lot of data, look at [partitioning](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/ddl-partitioning.html) your database. You may find you have ever growing tables. Partitioning is one way to address this without archiving data.

Sometimes you need little or no change to your application code.

Archiving is obviously another option

*Disclaimer: Any question like this is always going to be application specific. Always try to keep your architecture as simple as possible.*

Answer (score 3):

Since the replication is async, the [accepted solution](https://web.archive.org/web/20221010091826/https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25911359/how-to-split-read-only-and-read-write-transactions-with-jpa-and-hibernate/26026237) will cause hard to debug and hard to reproduce bugs with the second level cache. This is demonstrated [here](https://github.com/reda-alaoui/ro-rw-routing) .

[This automated test](https://github.com/reda-alaoui/ro-rw-routing/blob/af4502dffd266b8457f0f5f49670c461d7a9a399/src/test/java/me/redaalaoui/ro_rw_routing/RoRwRoutingApplicationTests.java) shows this can lead to manipulate incomplete entity graphs.

The cleanest path is to have one EntityManagerFactory per DataSource.

Answer (score 1):

If I correctly understand, 90% of the HTTP requests to your webapp involve at least one write and have to operate on master database. You can direct read only transactions to the copy database, but the improvement will only affect 10% of global databases operation and even those read only operations will hit a database.

The common architecture here is to use a good database cache (Infinispan or Ehcache). If you can offer a big enough cache, you can hope the a good part of the database reads only hit the cache and become memory only operations, either being part of a read only transaction or not. Cache tuning is a delicate operation, but IMHO is necessary to achieve high performance gain. Those cache even allow for distributed front ends even if the configuration is a bit harder in that case (you might have to look for Terracotta clusters if you want to use Ehcache).

Currently, database replication is mainly used to secure the data, and is used as an concurrency improvement mechanizme only if you have high parts of the Information Systems that only read data - and it is not what you are describing.

Answer (score 0):

You can also run a proxySQL infront of your DB nodes (Can be a galera cluster setup), and set query read write split rules, the proxy will distribute traffic according to the defined rule. Ex: SELECT query routed to read node whereas UPDATE queries or read-write transaction goes to write node.

Answer (score 0):

I think the question is general, not sure why the preferred answer steers it into Spring internals? Anyway, you may want to take a look [Apache ShardingSphere](https://shardingsphere.apache.org/), which has this feature:

```
Read/write Splitting
---------------------   

Read/write splitting can be used to cope with business access with high stress. ShardingSphere provides flexible read/write splitting capabilities and can achieve read access load balancing based on the understanding of SQL semantics and the ability to perceive the underlying database topology.
```

One thing I am concerned about is the "understanding of SQL semantics" claim, because how would any library "understand" if:`select myfunct(1) from dual` changes data in the function, or not.