# spring boot AbstractJPAConfiguration not found

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, spring-data-jpa

I am following this answer to have many data sources in my application, one for write and one for read. [How to split read-only and read-write transactions with JPA and Hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25911359/how-to-split-read-only-and-read-write-transactions-with-jpa-and-hibernate)

I want my class to extend AbstractJPAConfiguration but that class is not found.

I am using: spring-boot-starter-data-jpa
version: 2.4.4

any help please?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the class `AbstractJPAConfiguration` is not part of Spring, but is written by [Vlad Mihalcea](https://github.com/vladmihalcea) and can be found in his account at Github.

You can find the sourcecode at https://github.com/vladmihalcea/high-performance-java-persistence/blob/master/core/src/test/java/com/vladmihalcea/book/hpjp/util/spring/config/jpa/AbstractJPAConfiguration.java